# Standard UPDATE query very slow

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, *t_new* and *t_old*

*t_new* has ca. 39.000 records and *t_old* has ca. 27.000 records.

*t_new* has the same structure and columns of *t_old* and I am trying to fill certain columns that come NULL in the *t_new* with the data I have on the  *t_old* for the same columns.

I am using the following statement:

```
UPDATE t_new
SET `phone_number` = (SELECT `phone_number`
            FROM t_old
            WHERE  t_old.customerID =  t_new.customerID)
;
```

This query takes a lot of time to run and sometimes just crashes. What could be the origin of the problem and a viable solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for better performance, instead of uisng a subquery, you could try using an update with join

```
UPDATE t_new
inner join t_old on t_old.customerID =  t_new.customerID  
SET  t_new.phone_number  = t_old.phone_number
```

anyway be sure you have proper index on column customerID   for both the tables

Answer (score 1):

The sub-query is most likely to be the reason for the slow performance.

For better performance, try to avoid sub-query (use join instead),
and you can try to create an index on "customerID" in table "t_new".